# Distributed file system as a distributed buffer system?

Tags: amazon-s3, filesystems, buffer, distributed-computing, hdfs

#### The Problem

I've been developing an application which needs to support reads on a data object asynchronously with appending writes. In other words, a buffer. There will be many data objects at any given time.

I've been researching into available distributed file systems to find one which supports reading a file as it's being written to, but my search has come up with nothing. I know Amazon S3 does not support this from experience, while I am unsure about others such as HadoopDFS.

#### Solution: Chunking?

I have thought of chunking the data as a solution, which would involve splitting the incoming writes into n-byte chunks to write to the DFS as a whole. Chunks which are no longer needed can be deleted without interfering with the new data being written, as they are separate files on the DFS.

The problem with this strategy is it would result in pauses when a buffer reader consumes data faster than the buffer writer creates it. Smaller chunks would mitigate this effect, but not perfectly.

#### Summarized Questions

- Does a DFS exist which supports reading/writing an object as a buffer?
- If not, is chunking data on the DFS the best way to simulate a buffer?

Comment: Why simulate a buffer? What's wrong with using a buffer? http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/ (Although SQS is not a buffer, you'll have to write some code to enforce an ordering.)

Comment: I'm hoping I wouldn't have to simulate a buffer, but it may come down to that.

I cannot use SQS as I will be working with arbitrarily large files which will be using the system as a buffer as they pass through. I will also try to be as realtime as possible. 

SQS looks like it is mostly meant for queueing text messages. For something like a movie file, I don't think it would work well.

Answer (score 0):

Lustre (lustre.org) supports concurrent coherent reads and writes, including O_APPEND writes. Concurrency is controlled by the Lustre distributed lock manager (LDLM), which grants extent locks to clients and revokes the locks on conflict. Multiple readers and multiple concurrent writers to the same file are supported, they will see consistent file data, much like in case of a local file-system.